# CSS files is not working in HTML code on ASP.Net Core

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first ASP.NET Core assignment and I am having troubles with applying CSS. They're all under the wwwroot folder. I can view it normally via a browser but when I'm trying to see my project at ASP.NET, everything is messed up.
 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/880Wn.png) Thanks in advance for any help.

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using oClock.Contexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using oClock.Repositories;
using oClock.Models;
using oClock.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System.Text;
using System;
using oClock.Exceptions;

namespace oClock
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Jwt token authentication options
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Issuer"),
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Audience"),
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Key"))),
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                };
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionFilter));
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ModelValidationFilter));
            }).AddJsonOptions(a => a.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IInformationRepository, InformationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserInformationRepository, UserInformationRepository>();

            services.AddScoped<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }



            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
               // context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using oClock.Contexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using oClock.Repositories;
using oClock.Models;
using oClock.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System.Text;
using System;
using oClock.Exceptions;

namespace oClock
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Jwt token authentication options
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Issuer"),
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Audience"),
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Key"))),
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                };
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionFilter));
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ModelValidationFilter));
            }).AddJsonOptions(a => a.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());

            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IInformationRepository, InformationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserInformationRepository, UserInformationRepository>();

            services.AddScoped<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }



            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
               // context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml where I use css files**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Aesthetic by gettemplates.co
    Twitter: http://twitter.com/gettemplateco
    URL: http://gettemplates.co
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>oClock | Anasayfa</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Randevu takip sitesi" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="randevu takip, randevu" />
    <meta name="author" content="Harun Uz/Furkan Gerçek/Abdullah Oluk" />




    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.css">

    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Themify Icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/themify-icons.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/magnific-popup.css">

    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

    <!-- Owl Carousel  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <!--        ****************SYTLE.CSS DOSYASINDA SORUN VAR!!!!*****************
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css">
    -->
    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <
    <script src="~/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <div class="gtco-loader"></div>

    <div id="page">


        <!-- <div class="page-inner">  id="gtco-header" class="gtco-cover gtco-cover-md" role="banner" style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_2.jpg)" -->

        <header id="gtco-header" class="gtco-cover gtco-cover-md">

            <nav class="gtco-nav" role="navigation">
                <div class="gtco-container">

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="gtco-logo"><a href="index.html">oClock <em>.</em></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="slogan" class="col-xs-8 text-right menu-1">RANDEVU YONETİM SİSTEMİ</div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ************ GIRIS YAPMIS KULLANICININ GOREBILECEGI MENULER **************** -->
                <div id="header-login" class="gtco-container-login">
                <div class="col-xs-8-new text-right menu-1">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Randevu Al</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Takvimim</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Çıkış Yap</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>

            </nav>

        </header>

        <div class="gtco-section">


        </div>


        <footer id="gtco-footer" role="contentinfo">
            <div class="gtco-container">
                <div class="row row-p   b-md">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="gtco-widget">
                            <h3>Hakkımızda</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore eos molestias quod sint ipsum possimus temporibus officia iste perspiciatis consectetur in fugiat repudiandae cum. Totam cupiditate nostrum ut neque ab?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-1">
                        <div class="gtco-widget">
                            <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
                            <ul class="gtco-quick-contact">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-phone"></i> +1 234 567 890</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-mail2"></i> info@GetTemplates.co</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-chat"></i> Live Chat</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row copyright">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="pull-left">
                            <small class="block">&copy; 2018 Bütün hakları saklıdır.</small>
                            <small class="block">Designed by <a href="http://GetTemplates.co/" target="_blank">GetTemplates.co</a></small>
                        </p>
                        <p class="pull-right">
                            <ul class="gtco-social-icons pull-right">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- </div> -->

    </div>

    <div class="gototop js-top">
        <a href="#" class="js-gotop"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Easing -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <script src="~/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- countTo -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

    <!-- Stellar Parallax -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>

    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Main -->
    <script src="~/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So far, you have not even given us a proper problem description - “not working” isn’t one. Please go read [ask]. Then, get rid of the “I think my [...] is right” mindset. Don’t “think” or “assume” - **verify**. Your browser dev tools can help you easily spot stuff like 404s due to incorrect paths or other related issues, so you always go check there first.

Comment: Ah true,sorry this is my first question around here.
 So I am not getting any errors, its just isn't the way it should be. Everything is kinda messed up. You can view it normally if you open it from a browser but can't view it on .NET

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use your Shared/_Layout.cshtml for your layout?
Then edit your _Viewstart to this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

This will keep your layout on every page the same. except if you exclude it like this:

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ASP.NET Core MVC. It comes with good basic separation of concern.

[image]

And instead of repeating your header and footer for html in every cshtml of your project, why not use _Layout.cshtml?

[image]